# Translate Section name

Tags: localization, sections, craft3

I can see in the CP (craft 3) that my **sections** have a 'translatable' icon but I don't find anywhere in the UI to translate section names.

[image]

What's the best way to translate these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found how to do it through the UI but it's possible to add the section names in translation files as keys and then translate them in the views using `{{ "key_name" | translate }}`.

You must follow [this example](https://craftcms.com/support/static-translations) but keeping in mind the `translations` folder [changed its location and structure from Craft 2 to Craft 3](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/master/en/upgrade.md#static-translation-files).

You have to place it right under your project directory:

```
yourProject
|--templates
|--translations/
|---en/
|-----site.php
|---es/
|-----site.php
|--vendor
```